# Java Calendar Days Between Two Calendar Dates Inconsistency

Tags: java, calendar

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class FullYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(2011,2,9); 
        GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(2011,2,12); 
        long ms1 = cal1.getTime().getTime(); 
        long ms2 = cal2.getTime().getTime(); 
        long difMs = ms2-ms1; 
        long msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24; 

        System.out.println(difMs);
        System.out.println(msPerDay);

        double days = difMs / msPerDay;

        System.out.println(days);

        GregorianCalendar cal11 = new GregorianCalendar(2011,2,9); 
        GregorianCalendar cal22 = new GregorianCalendar(2011,2,19); 
        long ms11 = cal11.getTime().getTime(); 
        long ms22 = cal22.getTime().getTime(); 
        long difMs1 = ms22-ms11; 
        long msPerDay1 = 1000*60*60*24; 

        System.out.println(difMs1);
        System.out.println(msPerDay1);

        double days2 = difMs1 / msPerDay1;

        System.out.println(days2);

    }

}
```

This outputs 3.0 and 9.0 (I expect 10!!). This does integer division, so 9.0 is actually 9.95. However, my question is...

- The difference between February 9th and February 19th is 860400000 milliseconds, or 239 hours.
- The difference between February 9th and February 12th is 259200000 milliseconds, or 72 hours.

Shouldn't the first difference be 240 hours?

Comment: Set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds on your calendar objects (all 0), and then reevaluate the resut.

Comment: I get 3.0 and 10.0 running your code using Java 7u2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calculating the differences for [March](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MARCH), not February, and you have engulfed the onset of Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: Right and right. Accept in a second. I'm going to look for a way to overcome this.

Comment: Have you tried JodaTime? I think it handles stuff like this (counting natively in days instead of milliseconds).